# Is this possible to return an Object in Web Service in java

Tags: java, web-services

Hi all here I'm trying to return an userdefined Object in my web Service. But I failed in that. Is my way is correct, or the complete scenario is wrong...?

Please correct me, thanks in advance.

Calculator.java

```
package p1;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Calculator {

@WebMethod
public int calc(int a,int b){
    return a + b;
}
@WebMethod
public Student getData(){
    Student stdnt = new Student();
        stdnt.setName("Rakesh");
        stdnt.setNo(1);
    return stdnt;
}
@WebMethod
public Date getDate(){
    return new Date();
}
}
```

Student.java

```
package p1;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int no;
    public String name;
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

See Here I'm trying to return Student class Object, but its not working, that's my issue.

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: Should not be an issue. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Why are you not sending a json response?!

Comment: I'm using glassfish server, and its showing me `deployFailed`